# Turing machine that accepts strings $w$ of ${a,b,c}$ where $w = a^i b^j c^k$ and $i\ge j$, $j\ge k$, and $i,j,k \ge 0$

Tags: turing-machines

Basically a Turing machine that accepts strings that look something like aaabbcc or even aabc or abc. There just has to be at least one of each letter and they have to be in that order and there needs to be more or equal a's than b's and more or equal b's than c's. I just can't figure out how to do this with a deterministic Turing machine.